# NullPointException with Hibernate 4 and Spring 3.0.5 Intergration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I tried to create a Java program using Hibernate 4.1.6 and Spring 3.0.5. When i ran my app throwing NULLPOINT EXCEPTION. Anyone help me, please,

1. SpringBeans.xml:

   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">

   ```
   <!-- Database Configuration -->
   <import resource="config/spring/DataSource.xml"/>
   <import resource="config/spring/HibernateSessionFactory.xml"/>

   <!-- Beans Declaration -->
   <import resource="config/spring/UserBeans.xml"/>
   ```

   ```
   2. HibernateSessionFactory.xml
   ```

   ```
   <property name="dataSource">
     <ref bean="dataSource"/>
   </property>

   <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
      </props>
   </property>

   <property name="mappingResources">
       <list>
         <value>com/model/TblUser.hbm.xml</value>
       </list>
   </property>
   ```
2. DataSource.xml

   WEB-INF/classes/config/database/properties/database.properties
3. database.properties

   jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
   jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql:localhost:3306/auction_nms
   jdbc.username=root
   jdbc.password=root
4. UserBeans.xml

   ```
   <!-- User business object -->
   ```
5. UserDaoImpl .java

   public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {
       @Autowired
       SessionFactory sessionFactory;

   ```
   /*
    * @see com.dao.UserDao#save(com.model.TblUser)
    */
   @Override
   public void save(TblUser user) {
       sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(user);
   }
   ```

7.App.java

```
public class App {

    // get log4j handler
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(App.class);

    static TblUser              user   = new TblUser(2, "2", "2");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UserDao userDao = new UserDaoImpl();
            userDao.save(user);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.`enter code here`println(e);
        } finally {
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug(user);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: You should use UserDao from spring context, not create it with `new` operator. If you create it with `new`, Spring cannot inject SessionFactory and end up with NPE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating the `UserDAO` object by using the `new` keyword. You should start the spring container by loading the appContext, in your case `SpringBeans.xml`. 
If you use the `new` keyword Spring doesnt manage your dependencies, hence, your `sessionFactory` is never injected into the DAO instance.

This should be the contents of you `main()` instead of the current ones.

```
ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {
        "classpath*:/META-INF/SpringBeans.xml"
        });
appContext.getBean("userDao");
```

.. call your save on it.

Comment: The first of all, thanks your support. The exception was solved, but i met another exception. Please help me. - org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'userDao' is defined
Although i tried to define directly userDao in SpringBeans.xml file:
   <bean id="userDao" class="com.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl" >
     <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
   </bean>
Older code: ("<import resource="config/spring/UserBeans.xml"/>").
ps: location folder:
src--main
--java ...
--resource
    --config --spring -UserBeans.xml  
    -SpringBeans.xml

Comment: Hi Krishikensh, you don't still mind my comment. i found out solution :). Once more time, thanks your answer!!!